# What is a "Page Function"?

Tags: wpf

What is a "Page Function" in WPF and what have you used it for? Also, it this something you think Silverlight would benefit from?

Answer (score 16):

PageFunction is a cross between a Page and a Function (method). So basically, you can navigate to it like a page, but it can also return a value like a method. This is useful for when you want to show the user a page and receive feedback in the calling page. You could use a popup box of sorts, but in some patterns and situations, a page is preferable.

There's a good explanation of PageFunctions in [this article](http://www.paulstovell.com/wpf-navigation).

Comment: Ok, that does make a lot of sense.

Comment: Typically what you would think of as a wizard if you're old.